# Counting and generating perfect squares

Tags: python, perfect-square

I need some advice on how to write a Python program where it gives you a list of the first n perfect squares in list format. The output should look like this:

```
How many squares?: 5  
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
n = int(raw_input("How many squares? "))
```

Now for the next part I need to create a list of the first n squares.  Any suggestions on how?  Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: @justin: There are two parts to problem. Knowing the algorithm and implementing it in python. Provide the algorithm and then you can be guided on how to implement it with python

Comment: Thanks to all who helped Justin with his university assignment: your solutions are his solutions. Justin has been monitored by the course staff for some time now and will meet shortly with the Dean to discuss his future academic career.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[ a*a for a in xrange(1, n + 1) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

> Now for the next part i need to start to create a list of the first n squares. Any suggestions on how? Thank You for your time and advice.

This is something you can be helped with. For the other part, post your algorithm.

Use range to generate a list:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Use list comprehension to get list of x^2

```
>>> [x**2 for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>>
```

A more elegant answer is provided by Novikov

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(raw_input("How many squares? "))
map((2).__rpow__, range(1, n+1))
```

or

```
from operator import mul
n = int(raw_input("How many squares? "))
map(mul, *[range(1, n+1)]*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody mentioned generators - this is how you use them in this case:

```
def sq(n):
    i=0
    while i<n:
        i+=1
        yield i*i

if __name__=="__main__":
    n = int(raw_input("How many squares? "))
    print list(sq(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with map and a lambda function

```
n = int(raw_input("How many squares? "))
map(lambda x: x*x, range(n))
```

if you want it starting at 1

```
map(lambda x: x*x, range(1, n+1))
```

Comment: can u explain what map and lambda does?

Comment: @justin: these things are generally discouraged. No need to learn it, and it's bad style to write it. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
list_squares=[]
for a in xrange(1, n+1):
 list_squares.append(a*a)
print list_squares
```

where n is user input for number of squares he wants.

If `n=5` then the output looks like:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```